# SQL doing a count for a given date range

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

At the minute I'm doing query that counts the number of attempted transactions for a given date. But I want to make it so that I will be given output for a given date range, with each day listed individually.

```
select count(id)
from transactions
where service_id in ('1','2','3','4')
and date(created_at) = '2018-01-23';
```

As you can see, this will only return a count from one date. But how would I do this query for each date for a given range and print them one their own count column. If I can.

Comment: You need to group by, i.e. put 'group by created_at' at the end of your statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should print them as separate *rows* not separate *columns*:

```
select date(created_at), count(id)
from transactions
where service_id in ('1', '2', '3', '4') and
     date(created_at) >= '2018-01-01' and
     date(created_at) < '2018-01-24'
group by date(created_at)
order by date(created_at);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `group by` and `Having` to achieve this.

```
select count(id), created_at
from transactions
where service_id in ('1','2','3','4')
grouby created_at
HAVING date(created_at) BETWEEN '2018-01-23' AND '2018-01-28';
```